# Installing pyodbc on cygwin

Tags: python, pip, cygwin, pyodbc

I am running Cygwin under Windows 10 and when trying to install pyodbc
I have been searching for similar problems for multiple hours now but can't find anything helpful for me. As far as i understand there are some confilicting data type declarations but i don't know what to do.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks to anyone who is taking some of their time to help me!

```
$ pip install pyodbc
Collecting pyodbc
  Using cached pyodbc-4.0.14.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyodbc
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyodbc ... error
  Complete output from command /home/username/projects/my_project/env/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_m01a2yq/pyodbc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp90cam83npip-wheel- --python-tag cp34:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'pyodbc' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.cygwin-2.7.0-x86_64-3.4
  creating build/temp.cygwin-2.7.0-x86_64-3.4/src
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python3/python3-3.4.5-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python3-3.4.5-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python3/python3-3.4.5-1.x86_64/src/Python-3.4.5=/usr/src/debug/python3-3.4.5-1 -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.14 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.cygwin-2.7.0-x86_64-3.4/src/buffer.o
  cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
  cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wimplicit-function-declaration’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
  In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12:0:
  src/pyodbc.h:90:0: warning: "CDECL" redefined
   #define CDECL cdecl
   ^
  In file included from /usr/include/w32api/windef.h:8:0,
                   from /usr/include/w32api/windows.h:69,
                   from src/pyodbc.h:53,
                   from src/buffer.cpp:12:
  /usr/include/w32api/minwindef.h:83:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
   #define CDECL
   ^
  In file included from /usr/local/include/sql.h:19:0,
                   from src/pyodbc.h:56,
                   from src/buffer.cpp:12:
  /usr/local/include/sqltypes.h:105:26: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef short unsigned int WCHAR’
   typedef unsigned short   WCHAR;
                            ^
  In file included from /usr/include/w32api/minwindef.h:163:0,
                   from /usr/include/w32api/windef.h:8,
                   from /usr/include/w32api/windows.h:69,
                   from src/pyodbc.h:53,
                   from src/buffer.cpp:12:
  /usr/include/w32api/winnt.h:288:19: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef wchar_t WCHAR’
     typedef wchar_t WCHAR;
                     ^
  In file included from /usr/local/include/sql.h:19:0,
                   from src/pyodbc.h:56,
                   from src/buffer.cpp:12:
  /usr/local/include/sqltypes.h:261:33: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef long unsigned int ULONG’
   typedef unsigned long           ULONG;
                                   ^
  In file included from /usr/include/w32api/combaseapi.h:153:0,
                   from /usr/include/w32api/objbase.h:14,
                   from /usr/include/w32api/ole2.h:17,
                   from /usr/include/w32api/wtypes.h:12,
                   from /usr/include/w32api/winscard.h:10,
                   from /usr/include/w32api/windows.h:97,
                   from src/pyodbc.h:53,
                   from src/buffer.cpp:12:
  /usr/include/w32api/wtypesbase.h:92:15: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef unsigned int ULONG’
   typedef DWORD ULONG;
                 ^
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyodbc
  Running setup.py clean for pyodbc
Failed to build pyodbc
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
  Running setup.py install for pyodbc ... error
    Complete output from command /home/username/projects/my_project/env/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_m01a2yq/pyodbc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-2f4vknxq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/username/projects/my_project/env/include/site/python3.4/pyodbc:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyodbc' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.cygwin-2.7.0-x86_64-3.4
    creating build/temp.cygwin-2.7.0-x86_64-3.4/src
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python3/python3-3.4.5-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python3-3.4.5-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python3/python3-3.4.5-1.x86_64/src/Python-3.4.5=/usr/src/debug/python3-3.4.5-1 -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.14 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.cygwin-2.7.0-x86_64-3.4/src/buffer.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wimplicit-function-declaration’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12:0:
    src/pyodbc.h:90:0: warning: "CDECL" redefined
     #define CDECL cdecl
     ^
    In file included from /usr/include/w32api/windef.h:8:0,
                     from /usr/include/w32api/windows.h:69,
                     from src/pyodbc.h:53,
                     from src/buffer.cpp:12:
    /usr/include/w32api/minwindef.h:83:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
     #define CDECL
     ^
    In file included from /usr/local/include/sql.h:19:0,
                     from src/pyodbc.h:56,
                     from src/buffer.cpp:12:
    /usr/local/include/sqltypes.h:105:26: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef short unsigned int WCHAR’
     typedef unsigned short   WCHAR;
                              ^
    In file included from /usr/include/w32api/minwindef.h:163:0,
                     from /usr/include/w32api/windef.h:8,
                     from /usr/include/w32api/windows.h:69,
                     from src/pyodbc.h:53,
                     from src/buffer.cpp:12:
    /usr/include/w32api/winnt.h:288:19: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef wchar_t WCHAR’
       typedef wchar_t WCHAR;
                       ^
    In file included from /usr/local/include/sql.h:19:0,
                     from src/pyodbc.h:56,
                     from src/buffer.cpp:12:
    /usr/local/include/sqltypes.h:261:33: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef long unsigned int ULONG’
     typedef unsigned long           ULONG;
                                     ^
    In file included from /usr/include/w32api/combaseapi.h:153:0,
                     from /usr/include/w32api/objbase.h:14,
                     from /usr/include/w32api/ole2.h:17,
                     from /usr/include/w32api/wtypes.h:12,
                     from /usr/include/w32api/winscard.h:10,
                     from /usr/include/w32api/windows.h:97,
                     from src/pyodbc.h:53,
                     from src/buffer.cpp:12:
    /usr/include/w32api/wtypesbase.h:92:15: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef unsigned int ULONG’
     typedef DWORD ULONG;
                   ^
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/username/projects/my_project/env/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_m01a2yq/pyodbc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-2f4vknxq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/username/projects/my_project/env/include/site/python3.4/pyodbc" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_m01a2yq/pyodbc/
```

Comment: When you installed Cygwin did you install the g++ compiler?

Comment: @Brian im not sure if i installed it along with cygwin or later with apt-cyg, but it definitely have it installed now

Comment: It is very possible that pyodbc's setup.py is configured to install to a windows version of python or to a linux version of python, but not to the cygwin version of python. This means that you may have to add a case to the compile instructions for cygwin that is a merge of both other systems. You need to ask how to compile a c++ src that includes windows headers on cygwin.